# android ALooper_callbackFunc

Tags: activity, input, android-ndk, native

Как правильно инициализировать нативный лупер (`ALooper_addFd(...)`), и как именно связать с ним очередь ввода (`onInputQueueCreated(...){...AInputQueue_attachLooper(...);...}`) так, чтобы поступление данных в связанный с лупером дескриптор, провоцировало вызов функции типа: `ALooper_callbackFunc` ?
И стоит ли использовать такой способ обработки? Не будет ли быстрее (в смысле скорости работы программы) использование вызовов `ALooper_pollOnce(0,...)`, `ALooper_pollAll(0,...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для связи используется функция AInputQueue_attachLooper(...)
Но подход с ALooper_pollOnce(...) работает лучше и быстрее. В то время как ALooper_pollAll(...) это лишь обертка над циклом, в котором вызывается ALooper_pollOnce(...).